# Получить значения дочернего элемента из родительского

Tags: c#, winforms

*Возможно заголовок не самый правильный, не понимаю как его еще назвать.*

Есть `FlowLayoutPanel` которую заполняют картинки из определенной папки, коротко так:

```
PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();
pic.Parent = flowLayoutPanel;
```

А к этим картинкам добавляются `NumericUpDown` и `ComboBox`, вот так:

```
NumericUpDown nud = new NumericUpDown();
nud.Minimum = 1;
nud.ClientSize = new Size(100, 0);
nud.Location = new Point(0, 180);
nud.Parent = pic;

ComboBox cbx = new ComboBox();
cbx.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
cbx.Items.Add("10x15");
cbx.Items.Add("13x18");
cbx.Items.Add("15x21");
cbx.SelectedIndex = 0;
cbx.ClientSize = new Size(100, 0);
cbx.Location = new Point(100, 180);
cbx.Parent = pic;
```

В чем проблема: У `PictureBox` есть обработчик событий `MouseClick`

```
pic.MouseClick += PictureBox_MouseClick;
```

При нажатии на картинку фон этой картинки поменяется на красный, но **как я могу получить значения из `NumericUpDown` и `ComboBox` именно этой картинки? Как их нужно объявить?**

```
private void PictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pic = sender as PictureBox;

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        pic.BackColor = Color.Red;
        MessageBox.Show(nud.Value.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(cbx.Text);
    }
}
```

[image: После загрузки картинок]

[image: После нажатия на картинку]

После нажатия на картинку с котом, должны появиться значения `nud = 2` и `cbx = 13х18`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете унаследоваться от PictureBox и добавить свойства ваших компонентов, обращаясь к ним при обработке события. Да и создавать их в этом же наследнике, в конструкторе например, если логика позволяет.

Или же можете в словаре по ключу-PictureBox хранить ссылки на соответствующие дочерние контролы.

Можно ещё обратиться к свойству Controls у PictureBox, но придется делать это при каждом событии, что не очень хороший вариант.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: @Алексей если ответ вам помог, его можно пометить принятым, галочка слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:

```
foreach (NumericUpDown contr in pic.Controls.OfType<NumericUpDown>())
{
    NumericUpDown numericUpDown = contr;
    MessageBox.Show(numericUpDown.Value.ToString());
}

foreach (ComboBox contr2 in pic.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
{
    ComboBox cbxs = contr2;
    MessageBox.Show(cbxs.Text.ToString());
}
```